# Best way to send push notifications from the server to a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, websocket, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm making a chrome extension for a classified ads website. With the chrome extension users will be able to get latest lists from their watched categories/search query.

I am already working on a websocket server to send notifications to users, but this way I have to always have a socket connection open to every user.

My second approach was to use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/), but this will run the notification only when a user clicks the icon (as I've read), and I would rather have this done from my server

__

Are there any other possible solutions to send notifications to a chrome extension without the user clicking on the icon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Google's push infrastructure ― the very same that powers Android push notifications ― Google Cloud Messaging.

*Note: Firebase Cloud Messaging is presented as an upgraded version of GCM; while true, it's not natively supported by Chrome in a way that GCM is.*

[`chrome.gcm` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/gcm) is the one that works with it. See its documentation, as well as [GCM documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm), for details.

There's even a tutorial: [Implementing GCM Client on Chrome](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client)

But in a nutshell, your extension will register as a subscriber with GCM, pass the subscription ID to the server, and then the application server posts messages to GCM using those IDs.

You should also be able to use Firebase, if you're willing to implement it using the generic JS SDK; "this will run the notification only when a user clicks the icon" sounds pretty nonsensical ― a background page should be able to keep a listener alive and react, which is probably how your system works now. I would still recommend a native API, which should be compatible with Event pages.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Vielen dank

Comment: "As of April 10, 2018, Google has deprecated GCM. The GCM server and client APIs are deprecated and will be removed as soon as April 11, 2019. Migrate GCM apps to Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), which inherits the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus many new features. See the migration guide to learn more." https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client

Comment: @Protectorone Since official docs at https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client specifically mention Firebase, I'm assuming that this deprecation will be transparent to Chrome API. Though, of course, the _server_ component needs updating.

Answer (score -2):

Have you looked at the chrome.notifications API? It allows you to create rich notifications using templates and show these notifications to users in the system tray.

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications

You can have a connection to your socket server in the background script, listen for messages from your socket server and trigger an event that shows the notification.

Comment: You're answering the wrong question. Instead of answering "how to relay notifications to the extension in a way that doesn't use sockets", you're answering about presentation to the user.